# Custom Vision: remaining quota

Tags: python, microsoft-custom-vision

I have gotten a "Quota Exceeded" exception while calling `CustomVisionPredictionClient`

Is there a way to find out the remaining number of prediction calls in Custom Vision?

I cannot find any information in the documentation, other than that there is a limit of 10 thousand predictions per month.

Answer (score 0):

Limits depend on the pricing chosen:

- Free:
- 2 calls per second
- 10 000 calls per month
- Standard (S0):
- 10 calls per second

See pricing page on Azure website [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365):
[image: Pricing capture]

And also "limits and quota" page in docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/limits-and-quotas?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)

Regarding the "remaining quota", there's no easy way to get it.